# How to calculate transformed skin vertices?

Tags: three.js

The code I tried:

```
var transformedSkinVertex = function (skin, index) {
    var skinIndices = (new THREE.Vector4 ()).fromAttribute (skin.geometry.getAttribute ('skinIndex'), index);
    var skinWeights = (new THREE.Vector4 ()).fromAttribute (skin.geometry.getAttribute ('skinWeight'), index);
    var skinVertex = (new THREE.Vector3 ()).fromAttribute (skin.geometry.getAttribute ('position'), index).applyMatrix4 (skin.bindMatrix);
    var result = new THREE.Vector3 (), temp = new THREE.Vector3 (), tempMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4 (); properties = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'w'];
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        var boneIndex = skinIndices[properties[i]];
        tempMatrix.multiplyMatrices (skin.skeleton.bones[boneIndex].matrixWorld, skin.skeleton.boneInverses[boneIndex]);
        result.add (temp.copy (skinVertex).multiplyScalar (skinWeights[properties[i]]).applyMatrix4 (tempMatrix));
    }
    return result.applyMatrix4 (skin.bindMatrixInverse);
};
```

This works for T pose:

[image]

But with arms lowered some parts explode into angel-like shape:

[image]

Here is arms placed slightly differently:

[image]

My current theory is that this happens when there are > 2 bones. But... why?

All weights correctly add up to 1, as you can see above three.js renders the skin correcty.

Comment: no, r70. this project is a bit old.

Answer (score 4):

Resolved.

Correct line is

```
result.add (temp.copy (skinVertex).applyMatrix4 (tempMatrix).multiplyScalar (skinWeights[properties[i]]));
```

I did not think the order of multiplication by scalar would matter.

Comment: Lifesaver - THANK YOU.  Did you reverse engineer this from the shader?